# Why is this div being completely pushed out of it's parent?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm quite new to web development, and I'm trying to come up with a nice layout for a site I'm starting to make. I have it laid out so that there is a header, three columns in the middle, and a footer.

In the left column, which will be for navigation, I'm trying to have the nav links, then a border to separate, then some buttons. The div which will contain the buttons is being completely taken out of the left column and being pushed underneath it, and I have no idea why.

All the divs have `display: inline-block`, if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to be clear, I want the `#left-buttons` div to be placed just to the right of the `#left-nav` div, in the gap between the border of `#left-nav` and the border of `#site-left`.

Code:

```css
html, body, #site-content {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 0;
}

body {
 background: #fbfbfbf;
}

#site-content {
 overflow: auto;
}

#site-content > div {
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#site-top {
 height: 125px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 5px solid #000;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 border-top: 0;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 0;
 border-image-slice: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
}

#site-left, #site-right {
 height: calc(100% - 175px);
 width: 175px;
}

#site-left {
 border: 3px solid #222;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 0;
 border-image-slice: 1;
 box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
 -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
}

#site-left #left-nav {
 height: 100%;
 width: 135px;
 border: 2px solid #111;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 85%, #777 100%);
 -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 85%, #777 100%);
 -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 95%, #777 100%);
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 0;
 border-image-slice: 1;
}

#site-left #left-buttons {
 height: 100%;
 width: 40px;
}

#left-buttons .left-button {
 margin: auto;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#left-buttons .left-button.red {
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.95);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.75);
 box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}

#left-buttons .left-button.red:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(255,0,0,.8);
}

#left-buttons .left-button {
 transition: box-shadow .4s;
}

#left-buttons .left-button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#site-right {
 border: 3px solid #222;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,.85) 85%, #777 100%);
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-right: 0;
 border-image-slice: 1;
 box-shadow: -6px 0 10px -5px #333;
}

#site-content #site-main {
 height: calc(100% - 175px);
 width: calc(100% - 350px);
 min-width: 480px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

#site-bottom {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 5px solid #000;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 75%, #fff 100%);
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 0;
 border-image-slice: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>

  <title>Web Tests</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="site-content">
   
   <div id="site-top">
   </div>

   <div id="site-left">
    
    <div id="left-nav">
    </div>
    
    <div id="left-buttons">
     <!--<div class="left-button red">
     </div>-->
    </div>

   </div>

   <div id="site-main">
   </div>

   <div id="site-right">
   </div>

   <div id="site-bottom">
   </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-H28SdxWrZ387Ldn0qogCzFiUDDxfPiNIyJX7BECQkDE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- JQuery Color  -->

 </body>

</html>
```

The HTML elements in question are:
 - `<div id="site-left">`
 - `<div id="left-nav">`
 - `<div id="left-buttons">`

Comment: So you want your left-buttons inside left-nav right?

Comment: No, I want the left-buttons inside the site-left div, but to the right of left-nav.

Answer (score 1):

It's because both `#site-left #left-nav` and `#site-left #left-buttons` have 100% height. Change that to 50% or any othe value you like, and it will work:

(or just put content into these elements and erase the height parameter to let their height depend on the content)

```css
html,
body,
#site-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

#site-content {
  overflow: auto;
}

#site-content>div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#site-top {
  height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px #333;
}

#site-left,
#site-right {
  height: calc(100% - 175px);
  width: 175px;
}

#site-left {
  border: 3px solid #222;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0 10px -5px #333;
    background: red;

}

#site-left #left-nav {
  height: 50%;
  width: 135px;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 85%, #777 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 85%, #777 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 95%, #777 100%);
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

#site-left #left-buttons {
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

#left-buttons .left-button {
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#left-buttons .left-button.red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .95);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

#left-buttons .left-button.red:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
}

#left-buttons .left-button {
  transition: box-shadow .4s;
}

#left-buttons .left-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#site-right {
  border: 3px solid #222;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .85) 85%, #777 100%);
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  box-shadow: -6px 0 10px -5px #333;
}

#site-content #site-main {
  height: calc(100% - 175px);
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  min-width: 480px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#site-bottom {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 75%, #fff 100%);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -5px #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Web Tests</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="site-content">

    <div id="site-top">
    </div>

    <div id="site-left">

      <div id="left-nav">
      </div>

      <div id="left-buttons">
        <!--<div class="left-button red">
     </div>-->
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="site-main">
    </div>

    <div id="site-right">
    </div>

    <div id="site-bottom">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-H28SdxWrZ387Ldn0qogCzFiUDDxfPiNIyJX7BECQkDE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JQuery Color  -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok maybe I wasn't so clear as to what I wanted - what I want to happen is that the #left-buttons div is placed to the right of the #left-nav div, in the gap after the border. That's what I'm trying to achieve but I don't get why it doesn't go there in the first place given it worked with the main layout divs.

Comment: You know, most of the time it's much easier and clearer if you add a little bit of content into your elements which is similar to the content that later will be there. Because placing empty containers on the page is quite different from a real-world situation - you have to define width and height where *with*  content it's often not necessary, because the content defines that automatically...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. I did have a 'button' div inside the left-buttons div to test it, but obviously it was positioned below, which is my problem. I want to get the page layout at least somewhere near functional before actually adding the content.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always prune down your example code to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the problem. There simply is too much css in your snippet to clearly see where the problem lies.
(Plus that it wasn't entirely clear from the start what your desired result was, but that's solved now.)

So a simplified version of the problem is this:

```css
html, body, #site-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

#site-content > div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#site-left {
  height: 50%;
  width: 175px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
}

#site-left #left-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 135px;
  border-right: 2px solid #111;
}

#site-left #left-buttons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
}

/* Added for identification purposes */
#left-nav {font-size: 12px; color: #000; background: #AFA;}

#left-buttons {font-size: 12px; color: #000; background: #FF6;}
```

```html
<div id="site-content">

  <div id="site-left">

    <div id="left-nav">
      nav
    </div>

    <div id="left-buttons">
      buts
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

(Note that I also gave the two offending divs some background color, so that you can actually see where they are. That too was a problem with your original snippet, sorry.)

Now you want the "buts" bar to be to the right of the "nav" bar (in between the two black borders), but it isn't, because of two problems.

First of all, both the "nav" bar and the "buts" bar are set to the default `display: block`, because the `#site-content > div` selector doesn't apply to them, only to #site-left, and `display` doesn't inherit.
Solution: remove the `>` from the selector.

Then the second problem kicks in: Since #site-left is 175px wide, and it has a 3px right border, it only has 172 of space inside for the two bars. This isn't enough.
Solution: recalculate the width of the bars, taking the borders into account.

Example:

```css
html, body, #site-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

#site-content div {                  /* removed > */
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

#site-left {
  height: 50%;
  width: 175px;
  border-right: 3px solid #222;
}

#site-left #left-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 132px;                      /* subtracted 3 pixels */
  border-right: 2px solid #111;
}

#site-left #left-buttons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
}

/* Added for identification purposes */
#left-nav {font-size: 12px; color: #000; background: #AFA;}

#left-buttons {
  font-size: 12px; color: #000; background: #FF6;}
```

```html
<div id="site-content">

  <div id="site-left">

    <div id="left-nav">
      nav
    </div>

    <div id="left-buttons">
      buts
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```